# Is it possible to make a program that will use different circuit for each request? Even if the requests are parallel?

Tags: circuit, unlinkability

I want to make a program that will use new circuit for each request (even if the requests are parallel) to avoid linkability. Is it possible?

Comment: Sure, just create random Socks credentials for each TCP connection.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think so, at least natively. Looking at the [manual for Tor](https://2019.www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en), it doesn't look like there is any kind of functionality built in that would allow you to do that.

Theoretically, you could do something with Docker containers. Spin up a new instance of Tor itself in a container with every new request but then you would need something to trigger the new instance and then switch you to it automatically. It would be really janky, slow, and it might look like you are running a botnet. If Tor has any kind of bot protection, this is the kind of thing it might be looking for.

I honestly can't think of a good use case for this because it would not conceal your identify any better because Tor already changes your path automatically every 10 minutes. You can try contacting the developers directly through one of the mailing lists if you have specific technical questions.